# JQuery Datatable add new row,if the row is already present remove it and insert new row for that ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Tried to remove rows using following method

```
table.DataTable().row().remove().draw();
```

I tried add using the following methods

1) `table.dataTable().fnAddData(jsonObject);`

2) `table.DataTable().row.add(jsonObject).draw();`

Add is not working, it is removing the old data and again after redraw it is showing old data in that row.

At first i am making ajax call and fetching data from database after that i need to add data in client side without making ajax call.

```
      this.updateTableandMap=function(jsonObject){
    if(jsonObject!=null){
var curTimeStamp=$('tr#'+jsonObject.trackeeId+'>td:eq(0)>a').attr('data-date-time-stamp');
        if(jsonObject.dateAndTime>curTimeStamp){
            $('#records-short').DataTable().row( $('#records-short>tbody>tr#'+jsonObject.trackeeId+'')).remove().draw();    
        //  $('#records-short').DataTable().row.data(jsonObject).draw();
        //  $('#records-short').dataTable().fnAddData(jsonObject);  
        }else if(curTimeStamp==undefined){
            $('#records-short').DataTable().row( $('#records-short>tbody>tr#'+jsonObject.trackeeId+'')).remove().draw();
            $('#records-short>tbody>tr#'+jsonObject.trackeeId+'').remove();

            $('#records-short').DataTable().row.add(jsonObject).draw();
        }
    }

    };
```

Comment: please share your script

Comment: Hi @HiralNayak I have shared the code.

Comment: When you redraw the table are you running your AJAX query again? If so this would cause the table to repopulate with the old data.

Comment: Hey @user3932103 - can you reproduce the error in the fiddle from my now deleted answer? http://jsfiddle.net/ayz8hzcL/ I guess I misunderstood your problem, and not sure what it is - there may be more in this as you wrote "_At first i am making ajax call and fetching data from database after that i need to add data in client side without making ajax call_" ...

Comment: Hi @davidkonrad , Thanks for the reply, its perfectly working fine now. we are doing server side pagination so we altered code in datatable library.Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way in your script

```
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('.dataTable').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(row);
```

Comment: Hi,remove is working fine but add is not happening, it is caching old data.

Comment: then you use dataTable().fnAddData( )

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444296/jquery-datatables-add-new-row